# why tomcat is not aware of refactoring package name in eclipse

Tags: java, refactoring, tomcat6, renaming

I changed few packages names in my JAVA project but when starting tomcat again after the change, it tries to get the old package name.(throwes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

I get the following exception when trying to re-build my application:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6eb38a
 com.project.linkedin.LinkedInService
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.linkedin.LinkedInService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

what am I doing wrong?
is there a need to change something in the tomcat properties as well?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? (In JSP code, a Servlet, ...?) Post the error text output by Tomcat

Comment: I changed the package name from com.project.linkedin.LinkedInService to com.afeka.project.linkedin.LinkedInService and this is what i get: org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6eb38a
 com.project.linkedin.LinkedInService
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.linkedin.LinkedInService
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526).....

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exception to that? - will make it more readable :)

Comment: Rebuild the code and try again.

Comment: Rebuild does not fix it....

Comment: check your web.xml, probably it references LinkedInService

Comment: Yes1 this is the reason1

Answer (score 2):

Fix your web.xml, probably it references LinkedInService with old package name